# Trouble with named pipes and fortran

Tags: linux, fortran, named-pipes, gfortran

I try to establish communication between some fortran processes via named pipes. However, considering even a very simple toy example I run into trouble. Here is my code:

```
  program testfifo

  implicit none

  integer status

  write(*,*) "hello"
  call flush()

  open(unit=11,file="MyNamedPipe",action='write',form ='unformatted'
 $     ,iostat=status);
  close(11)

  write(*,*) "by"
  call flush()

  return
  end program testfifo
```

If I run it with a normal file it works:

```
/fortran > rm -f MyNamedPipe && touch MyNamedPipe
/fortran > gfortran -o testfifo testfifo.f 
/fortran > ./testfifo 
 hello
 by
```

However, running with a fifo my program gets stuck:

```
/fortran > rm -f MyNamedPipe && mkfifo MyNamedPipe
/fortran > gfortran -o testfifo testfifo.f 
/fortran > ./testfifo 
 hello
^C
```

I don't get any error messages. In addition, I tried altering the open statement formatted <-> unformatted, with  err=100 for error handling etc., but it didn't help. Here are some of my system stats:

Linux lin45 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
gfortran 4.6.2
gcc 4.6.2
g++ 4.6.2

I'm searching the web for a solution of this problem for quite a while now. I would be very happy if someone could help me. Also, if someone is able to run the code without trouble, I would be interested if this is maybe due to any system/compiler issues. thx.

Note: The program I'm actually interested in needs to communicate between #n processes, thus , I think, I can't use normal pipes. Furthermore, there is already a version of the code set up with pipes. However, it only runs on a Mac. My task is to run it under Linux. The Mac specifications are:

Mac OS X 10.7.5
Xcode 4.5
gfortran 4.6.1
gcc 4.2.1
g++ 4.2.1

Comment: What is the `return` before the `end program` supposed to do? It is not allowed in the main program and many compilers will throw an error. Also there is no sensible reason for it.

Comment: The dollar sign is also suspicious, is it actually in column 6?

Comment: I was told that the pipe might not close correctly without the return. The $ sign is a line break. I had never trouble with that before. Without linebreak I become a compilation error. Deleting the return does not result in any changes.

Comment: If I write the open statment in one line I get: `code /fortran > gfortran -o testfifo testfifo.f 
testfifo.f:12.67:

      open(unit=110,file="MyNamedPipe",action='write',err=100,form='unfo
                                                                   1
Error: Invalid value for FORM specification at (1) `

Comment: You were definitely told wrong then, with `return` it doesn't compile by 2 of my 3 compilers. And even not with gfortran when I enable strict standard conformance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me. Somehow, `action="write"` is problematic.

```
    program testfifo

    implicit none

    integer status

    write(*,*) "hello"
    call flush()

    open(unit=11,file="MyNamedPipe",access='stream'                    &
 &   ,form ='unformatted', iostat=status)
    write(11) status
    print *, status
    close(11)

    write(*,*) "by"
    call flush()

    end program testfifo
```

I used the `stream` access because of http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=30162